# ember.js route Transitioned, but Template not render?

Tags: templates, ember.js, routes, router

about this reps [demo](https://github.com/icai/yodemo).

**route:**

```
  this.resource('index',{path:'/'}, function(){
     this.route('login',{path:'/login'});
     this.route('signup',{path: '/signup'});

  })
```

index

- login

- signup

---

index -- render  `index.hbs` -> `index_login.hbs`

index.login --render `index.hbs` -> `index_login.hbs`

index.signup --render  `index.hbs` -> `index_signup.hbs`

---

I have no idea! I just want to reuse `index.hbs`, but I don't how to control.

Comment: Can u put ur example on emberjs.jsbin.com. It will make it easier to just correct the code.

Comment: @blessenm http://emberjs.jsbin.com/titabaxe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Is this what u need? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/titabaxe/2/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code:

```
<div class="well">
<h1>index</h1>

{{outlet}}


 Welcome Ember.js! {{#link-to 'index.signup'}}signup{{/link-to}}

</div>
```

By default (not overriding route.renderTemplate), the **{{outlet}}** will be automatically updated when the content of index/login.hbs or index/signup.hbs when you enter on each specific route.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index/login">
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index/singup">
```

To show Login when you transition to 'index' (IndexRoute), you could define your IndexRoute or IndexIndexRoute to redirect to IndexLoginRoute.

```
Yodemo.IndexIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

   beforeModel: function(transition) {
     this.transitionTo('index.login');
   }

});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/titabaxe/3/edit

Comment: can I help me to fix it? I have no idea.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/titabaxe/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: can you tell me why it throw error, it is a ember.js bug, or my code, when I switch login to signup and than repeat to do again? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/titabaxe/5/edit I try to add the link to toggle switch, it throw "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unchain' of undefined"

Comment: {{#if Signedup}} --> first letter must be lower case.